# Retrieve client cert in Servlet when using mutual authentication?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, ssl, client-certificates

I am building a web application using Java and Tomcat 7.0.

I have a self-signed certificate (in the future I'll get an official one) on the server side, and I've added a client's root certificate to its truststore. I've already set a required two-way authentication for https protocol on port 3443 with the following lines on the server.xml file:

```
<Connector port="3443" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" 
        truststoreFile="server.keystore" truststorePass="keystore password" 
        keystoreFile="server.keystore" keystorePass="keystore password" 
        clientAuth="true" keyAlias="serverkey" 
        sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

This is working and I can only access the system with a valid certificate.

I was now wondering how I can get a property of this used certificate on my Servlet to log the user in based on his certificate. All certificates used in this context will have a different CN so I want to use that to identify the user.

Comment: *"I have a self-signed certificate (in the future I'll get an official one)"* - Try [Startcom](http://www.startcom.org/) or [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/). They offer free Class 1 server certificates. The certificates are trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. Class 1's are domain validated via email and *don't* allow wildcards. If you need a wildcard, then you'll have to purchase a Class 2 or higher. Startcom and CAcert charge for revocation, if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Would you know how to get the user's certificate information from a Java Servlet?

Comment: Do you have access to the SSL/TLS [`session`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSession.html) object? If so, try `Certificate certs[] =   (Certificate[])session.getPeerCertificates()` or `X509Principal peer = (X509Principal)session.getPeerPrincipal()`.

Comment: How can I get the SSL/TLS session object? I tried 
`String id = request.getSession().getId();
context = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
SSLSession session = context.getServerSessionContext().getSession(id.getBytes());
Certificate certs[] =   (Certificate[]) session.getPeerCertificates();`
But session is null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to import `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` and . In your `doGet(...)` method, use the following:

```
String cn = null;
X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req
    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
if (certs != null) {
  String dn = certs[0].getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
  // parse the CN out from the DN (distinguished name)
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|,)CN=([^,]*)(,|$)");
  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(dn);
  if(matcher.find()) {
    cn = matcher.group(2);
  }
} else {
  // no certificate provided
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! Just a small correction: `Matcher matcher = p.matcher(dn); if(matcher.find()) cn = matcher.group(2);`. `find()` returns a `boolean`, so `group()` can't be called on it. (I still have to wait two hours to award you with the bounty)